# Controlling position & height when window is shrunk

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a weird CSS situation here. I am building my new portfolio which is responsive and parallax. If you take a look here, in the first section you will see a desk: http://daniellebrittanydesigns.com/new-portfolio/

The desk is in different parts/divs. The main part of the desk (all the items) is an image. The table/wood section of the desk is a background image in a div below it because I need it to stretch across, yadda yadda.

The wood part is set 200px high (because the div has no content), and positioned top:-200px so the items in the desk will look like theyre "sitting" on it.

When you shrink the window, the main desk image shrinks, but the wood part of the desk maintains its height and rides up the image, underlapping the window eventually, etc.

I've been playing with height, position, margins, etc - cannot find a solution that will make the .desk-wood shrink & maintain position along with the desk-main image.

Any CSS tips would help - thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here for you.

First start playing with the wood height and position using percentages. With RWD it is important that elements have a fluid structure, and setting static widths and heights are not going to help in your situation. You can also mirror that same % to the fixed positioning as well.

Your other option would be to use media queries to set the width dynamically as the page width shrinks or expands.

Heck, you might find it to your liking to do a combination of the two options.